# How to change the value of a YAML variable between tasks inside the same job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

How to **set a new value of a YAML variable** in YAML file **through a task, and the subsequent task will display the new value using powershell**? (both **tasks are in the same job**)

I am trying with below code, but **its not working. The second/subsequent task STILL gets the initial value** even when the first task set a new value to that YAML variable

```
stages:
  - stage: tst
    displayName: tst_stage

    jobs:
      - deployment: 
        displayName: 'test 1'
        environment: 'test 1'

        variables:
        - name: someName
          value: "someValue"
```

**First task that will set/update the value of the variable** :

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    name: "task1"
    displayName: this is task1
    inputs:

      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $newValue = "ThisIsNewValue"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someName;isOutput=true]$newValue"
```

**Second task will display the variable with new value** :

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    name: "task2"
    displayName: this is task2
    inputs:

      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "the new value of the variable is : $(someName)"
```

Now the **expected output** of the task 2 should be :

```
the new value of the variable is : ThisIsNewValue
```

But for some reason the **actual output** that I got is the initial value :

```
the new value of the variable is : someValue
```

Comment: Does it work if you take the "isOutput=true" off the set command?

Comment: Already tried that and still, the initial value is being printed.

Comment: try referring to it as `$(task1.someName)` - this syntax should work within the same job.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some workarounds! I was able to set the variable successfully, I realize that I am missing a semi-colon (;) when i did your suggestion earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line of code from :

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someName;isOutput=true]$newValue"
```

to :

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someName;]$newValue"
```